# Write a function for traces in a bar chart

Tags: pandas, plotly

I created a pivot table:

```
df = data.pivot_table(index='col_A', columns='col_B', values='col_C', fill_value=0)
```

The dataframe df is a 10*25 dataframe. I want to plot all the columns in a single graph as traces. However, it would be super tedious to write code for all 25 traces. Is there a way I can write a function like:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.tools as tls
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
iplot([go.Bars(x=df.index, y=df[col], name=col for col in df.columns)])
```

The above code is giving me an error of invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am created example for your better understanding:

```
# import what we need
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,1,1,0],
                   "B":[1,1,0,0],
                   "C":[1,0,0,0]
                   })
# Convert names of columns in a list
traceslist = df.columns.tolist()
# Check list
print(traceslist)
# Create a function that will create as many traces for us as we need
def tracing(column):
   trace = go.Bar(
         x = df.index,
         y = df[column],
         # Parameters above specify what you would see if hover on any column
         name = column,
         text=column,
         textposition='auto',
         hoverinfo="x+y")
   return trace
# Create data
data = []
# Fill out data with our traces
for i in range(len(traceslist)):
   eachtrace = tracing(traceslist[i])
   data.append(eachtrace)
# Optional: create layout
layout = go.Layout(
      # Set title to plot
      title = "Bam!",
      # Choose one of the barmode below and comment another
      barmode="stack",
      #barmode="group"
      )
# Create figure with all we need to plot
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
# Use offline plot without connection to plotly site
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='Bam.html')
```

In code above just use function to create `traces`. And using `for` loop after it to get all the `traces` in `data`.
What difference between two `barmode` parameter you can see here:
[image: barstack]
1) `barmode="stack"`;
[image: bargroup]
2) `barmode="group"`.

You can create a much more beautiful plots (check official docs for [bar chart](https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/)), just specify additional parameters.